# Unit testing javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I finished my first unit test course, and it made me confused!
In the course, we used Mocha + Chai to build a small app with the BBD approach.
I got the idea of why should I build the test first and then write the code. But I don't understand when and what?
Should I use testing even for small apps? Should I test every code that I intend to write?
And how can I continue to learn about testing? Can you recommend me a good video course?

Regards.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be quiet helpful for you

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8Jl85FJz4E&list=PLw5h0DiJ-9PAdZwGJCYb7a9P2mJHayQQ3

Answer (score 0):

writing your test first helps guide in writing your code. When you write your test  first it fails when you run it and then you write your code and make it pass. That way you are sure your code does what you expect it to do. jasmine is also good for testing your js code.
yes you should write test for every app you are building first before writing the code, it's best practice and it helps you with the quality control/assurance of your app

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/wiki

https://jasmine.github.io/